# Can ASPX/PHP page size with many switch cases impact the parformance

Tags: php, asp.net, performance

Suppose We have a single ASPX/PHP file as a REST service that just in page load we use the switch case to direct the user to the desired function and return some values. My question is if the functions of this page exceed from 1000 say will this impact the performance and the response time?

Sample code could be something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        string ServiceOutput = "";
        string Function = Request.Form["Function"];
        switch (Function) {
            case "GetPluginsInfo":
                ServiceOutput = GetPluginsInfo();
                break;

            case "demo":
                ServiceOutput = Request.Form["Message"];
                break;

                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .

        }
        Response.Write(ServiceOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception Error) {
        Response.Write(Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd worry less about performance and more about maintainability and readability. 1000 cases?! Can't this switching be done in a different, more logical fashion?

Comment: I know it is seems odd at first but I need to put all the functions in one page as a project requirement. seems KBoek has better code fashion to offer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a Dictionary<string, string> that contains all your functions, and then use Reflection to execute the corresponding method? Not sure about the performance, but more neat. Your Dictionary should be static and somewhere in your business logic, so that you don't have to populate it at each PostBack.

```
static Dictionary<string, string> AllFunctions;

protected void Page_Load()
{
  string ServiceOutput;

  var function = Request["Function"];
  var method   = AllFunctions[function];
  var output   = GetType().GetMethod(method).Invoke(this, null);

  ServiceOutput = output;
}
```

If populating the Dictionary and/or the lookup is slow, you might even go for a solution where each possible value in Request.Form["Function"] has its own method. That would require you to have method names that are exactly the same as the function thought, which not always is ideal.

```
static Dictionary<string, string> AllFunctions;

protected void Page_Load()
{
  var ServiceOutput = GetType().GetMethod(Request["Function"]).Invoke(this, null);
}

// this would require you to have a method like this:
public string GetPluginsInfo()
{
  return "This is the result";
}

public string demo()
{
  return "You requested a demo";
}
```

I didn't test this code, so it might need small adjustments to function, but the purpose is to propose a conceptual solution.

Comment: that seems promising KBoek. I'm interested in the second code block. humm, but how about the performance. if there are 100s of functions and the user have requested TheLastFunctionInThePage() method?

Comment: As for the first code block, the Dictionary lookup might affect performance, but a 1000 items in a Dictionary sounds like nothing to worry about. The second code block's performance is only influenced by Reflection (finding the method based on a string value).

Comment: If this was how your AV software matched patterns, it'd take a week to load each file. If we're talking PHP here Why not: <?php include_once($some_base_path . $function) or die('not imlpemented'); ?>

Comment: Who's talking about loading files?

Comment: symcbean we are talking about implementing all function in one place not including any file

Comment: For php we may use this syntax:
call_user_func: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 0):

Sure, of course it's slower to process up to 1000 case conditions than say, 10.

If this is all you're doing, it's probably not even much compared to the amount of processing that goes into displaying a web page built with the average MVC framework.

The important question is how does this perform in the real world, though? Have you noticed there is a performance problem? I'd try a load test on it and see whether the response time is excessive.

Comment: Alex I'm waiting for the test results :) really appreciate the effort :)